# Laravel redirect appends url to base-url

Tags: url, redirect, laravel, nginx, laravel-forge

first of all, sorry if that question has been answered in another thread, but I spent quite some time researching it and nothing. I did find an old post without answers here ([Url redirect append new url to the old url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184047/url-redirect-append-new-url-to-the-old-url)).

**Here is my problem:**

When redirecting in Laravel and **only on my developement server**, the new url gets appended to the old one. 
So for example, let's say I am on adomain.com/login and the form action is set to URL::route('doLogin') <=> adomain.com/doLogin. When displaying the page, the form action is set to `"adomain.com/login/http://adomain.com/doLogin"`

What I don't understand is that the exact same code **works on my production server**, with the exact same settings.

**Here is my setup:**

I have two Laravel Forge provisioned servers on Digital Ocean(Ubuntu, NginX). I used the same configuration for both as one is my production server and the other one is my dev server/test server. I use BitBucket to commit my changes on branches (master for production and dev for development).

Can someone help me understand/fix this issue?

Thanks,
Stef

**** **Update**

Thanks for your suggestions, I am not sure how I can add the http. I am using Laravel as follow:

*View:*

```
Form::open(array('url'=>URL::route('adminLogin'), 'class'=>'form-horizontal'))
```

*Routes:*

```
Route::get ('admin/login', array('as' => 'adminLogin', 'uses'=>'AdminAuthController@showLogin'));
Route::post('admin/login', 'AdminAuthController@postLogin');
Route::get ('admin/logout', 'AdminAuthController@getLogout');
```

And this is the html I get for the form on the page:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://adomain.com/http://adomain.com/admin/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
```

My local environement is LAMP: **It works perfectly**

My developement environment is Ubuntu 14.04 with NginX, MySql and PHP: **It does not work**

My production environement is Ubuntu 14.04 with NginX, MySql and PHP: **It works perfectly**

I am completely clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has happened to me alot and i found that the base url needs the http or https included. this also happens when you create a html link and write it like this:

href="adomain.com/login"

you have to write out the whole link including the http otherwise ull have the same issue as above.

href="http://adomain.com/login"

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try that and let you know how it went. However, I have a hard time understanding why the code works in my local environment, on my production sever but fails on my dev/test server.

Comment: it probably has to do with the environment. not sure if your working on mac or windows locally versus what you use for production, but i'm sure the same issue will arise when you test it.

Comment: Thank you Sarmen, what's weird is that it react differently on 2 similar environments. I have updated my question to add more details regarding your suggestions.